# How did they shoot Alf's scenes?

Tags: character, muppets, alf

As per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALF_(TV_series)) page of *ALF*,

> *ALF* is an American sitcom that aired on NBC from September 22, 1986, to March 24, 1990.**
>
> The title character is Gordon Shumway, a friendly extraterrestrial nicknamed ALF (an acronym for Alien Life Form), who crash lands in the garage of the suburban middle-class Tanner family. The series stars Max Wright as father Willie Tanner, Anne Schedeen as mother Kate Tanner, and Andrea Elson and Benji Gregory as their children, Lynn and Brian Tanner. ALF was performed by puppeteer Paul Fusco, who co-created the show with Tom Patchett.

in this drama some scenes their showing Alf's full body & his walking with his legs. Alf is shorter than 3ft.

So my question is when they shooting Alf's scene's did they used a Real person inside Alf's suite or did they used a Muppet all the time?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the Wikipedia page for [Mihaly "Michu" Meszaros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michu_Meszaros), he was an actor who donned the costume of ALF in full body shots.

It's also in his bio on the [imdb](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0582361/?ref_=nmbio_bio_nm) page.